# how to allow only two users to access firebase database to perform read and write operations?I have tried to do so but i am able to add only 1 user

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

```
 {

  "rules": 

        {
        ".write":"auth.uid ==='yoz4SkfUu3gv1QZt8dVFsF4jj9J2','yoz4SkfUu3gv1QZt8dVFsF4jj9J2'"
        ".read":"auth.uid ==='yoz4SkfUu3gv1QZt8dVFsF4jj9J2'"
      }

}
```

> Error saving rules - Line 6: Rule expressions may not contain ',' operator.
>   Whenever I try adding 2 users based on their uids it shows error like above mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use a [logical or](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#_or) operation for this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": "auth.uid === 'yoz4SkfUu3gv1QZt8dVFsF4jj9J2' || auth.uid === 'yoz4SkfUu3gv1QZt8dVFsF4jj9J2'",
    ".read": "auth.uid ==='yoz4SkfUu3gv1QZt8dVFsF4jj9J2'"
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy you solved my problem.I was stuck here since last 1 hour